# Use regex to find a line and insert a line above

Tags: c#, regex

I have a multi-line text box on my web page. I'm pasting document contents like shown below into it and I'd like to find a pattern and insert a line of text above it.

```
              RANDOM TEXT Title 123 AB
Data 01
              ABC RAND Title 345 CB
Data 02
```

Is there a way to find all **Title** words and insert a line of text above it? Like the following?

```
I WANT TO SPLIT HERE
              RANDOM TEXT Title 123 AB
Data 01

I WANT TO SPLIT HERE
                ABC RAND Title 345 CB
Data 02
```

Comment: This question is very similar to another of your questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108348/trying-to-split-a-document-by-section-title-using-regex . Neither is a programming question, neither shows any real effort from you to solve the question.

Comment: This is actually a fairly normal question, and definitely doesn't fit "why is this code not working". OP is clear, he needs to have certain behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:
`(\n|^)[^\n]+Title[^\n]+`

`\n` = new line
`^` = start of string/document
`[^x]` = not x
`[^x]+` = many not x's
`|` = alternative

Replace with:
`I WANT TO SPLIT HERE\n$0`

`$0` = anchor to matched text (0 is everything)

To figure these things out try using this:

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you really search a single word "Title", you don't even need `regex`.

```
using System.Linq;
. . . . .  .
List<string> lines = myTb.Split(new Char[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int index;
while (index < lines.Length)
{
     if (lines[i].IndexOf(" title ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
     {
         lines.Insert(index, "my insert text into new line");
         // we just added new line, so current line is index + 1 
         index++; 
     }

    index++;

}
myTb.Lines = string.Join(lines, "\n\r");
```

Notice - can't use for-loop because collection is mutating. And this will be [most likely] faster than regex. Try this ant time vs regex option and comment my answer with result of timing. Thanks

Comment: @Rod if you saw my initial answer - it was for win forms. Now, I fixed it for asp.net